# A specific type of optimal control problem

Tags: optimization, control-theory, optimal-control

I recently encountered the following optimal control problem

\begin{alignat}{3}
\min_u              &\quad&  J = 50(x(2)-0.5)+\int_{0}^{2} u^2(t)dt  &&          & \\
\text{s.t: } &\quad&  \frac{dx}{dt} = u, \quad x(0)=a, \quad |u|\leq1
\end{alignat}

I am a novice in optimal control and optimization, in general. I cannot figure to how to solve this, so any help would be appreciated. How does one approach such a control problem with the inequality constraint and the integral? Also $ x(2) $ seems to complicate things. Is there an analytic solution? I thank all helpers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrating $\dot x = u$ with initial condition $x(0) = a$,

$$ x (2) = a + \int_{0}^2 u (t) \, {\rm d} t $$

and, thus, the cost function is

$$ J (u) =  (50 a - 25) + \int_{0}^2 \left( u^2 (t) + 50 \, u (t) \right) {\rm d} t $$

Note that

$$\arg\min_{-1 \leq u \leq 1} \left( u^2 + 50 \, u \right) = -1$$

---

[optimization](/questions/tagged/optimization) [control-theory](/questions/tagged/control-theory) [optimal-control](/questions/tagged/optimal-control)

Comment: Thank you so much